# Fifa 12 - Will the online servers be shutdown?

Tags: xbox-360, fifa-12

I'm looking to buy fifa 12 on Xbox, but I know ea have shut down the online servers for the previous fifa games. They have added the option to buy a online pass, will buying this pass mean fifa 12 will not be shut down in the near future?

I've had a look on the ea site, and they don't mention online server shutdowns for past April this year.

http://www.ea.com/1/service-updates

Answer (score 2):

The online pass doesn't guarantee that the service won't be shutdown, it's only there to allow you to play online. For people who buy the game firsthand, they should receive an online pass in the box with the game. Those that purchase the game used, etc., have to purchase the online pass to play online.

Given their history, they will likely shutdown online play for Fifa 12 sometime in the future. Any date would be speculation, but Fifa 11 is shutdown already as you can see in the list you posted.

Comment: Did Fifa 11 have the online pass? If so then its almost a certainty that fifa 12 will be shut down as you said. Thanks.

Comment: @Cadab You can be pretty certain they will shut it down, it is just a matter of when.  In the link you site (which I think is the best source for this information) EA mentions a rule of thumb for closing when a games activity falls to "fewer than 1% of all peak online players across all EA titles -- where it’s no longer feasible to continue the behind-the-scenes work involved with keeping these games up and running."  With annual franchise title like Fifa, I'd presume that condition occurs fairly quickly once the next iteration is released.